# Python создание полосы прогресса на изображении

Tags: python, pillow

Подскажите, как я могу реализовать полосу (progress bar) в виде изображения?
Например есть входные данные: 20%
Значит нужно вернуть изображение на котором полоса будет заполнена на 20%
Что для этого можно использовать? Думал насчет pillow, но совершенно не нашёл примеров. Нужно это мне для ботов. (Нужно возвращать картинку со шкалой)

Comment: Не нашли примеров рисования на картинке в pillow?

Comment: "Например есть входные данные: 20% Значит нужно вернуть изображение на котором полоса будет заполнена на 20%"

Comment: Пример расчета длины полосы и наложения ее на изображения мне нужно, а не "пример рисования на картинке"

Comment: У картинки берете ширину в пикселях, рассчитываете от ширины пиксели в процентах, например для 600 пикселей 20% это 120 (`600 * (20 / 100)`). Рисуете, например прямоугольник с такой шириной (высоту и положение относительно левого края сами придумайте) через ImageDraw.Draw.rectangle: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.rectangle . А так, подобные вопросы требуют вашего кода или его идеи :)

Comment: Спасибо за пример, буду пробовать.

Comment: Пробуйте, а так, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Answer (score 1):

Накидал [пример рисования простой полосы прогресса](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/b5e462a8563f94e7e3a7357be7dbe6f9dc54c07c/pil_pillow__examples/draw_progress_on_image/main.py#L11):

```
# pip install Pillow
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw


def draw_progress(image: Image, percent: int) -> Image:
    if percent < 0:
        return image

    if percent > 100:
        percent = 100

    width, height = image.size

    progress_width = width * (percent / 100)
    progress_height = height * (10 / 100)  # Пусть будет 10% от высоты

    x0 = 0
    y0 = height * (80 / 100)  # 80% от высоты
    x1 = x0 + progress_width
    y1 = y0 + progress_height

    image = image.copy()

    drawer = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    drawer.rectangle(xy=[x0, y0, x1, y1], fill=(0, 255, 0))  # RGB, green

    return image


if __name__ == '__main__':
    image_file = "input.jpg"
    image = Image.open(image_file)

    for percent in (5, 15, 75, 100):
        img = draw_progress(image, percent)
        img.save(f'output/image_{percent}%.png')
        img.show()
```

---

Результат `5%` -> `15%` -> `75%` -> `100%`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]