# Прогресс бар Pillow

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, pillow

Долго и упорно пытаюсь найти информацию как с помощью модуля pillow можно сделать прогресс бар. Была идея просто отрисовать линии и через условие их заполнять, но это очень нудный процесс(говно-код). Есть какие-то идеи?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/483400/ вам не подойдёт ?

Comment: Вот тут посмотрите - (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/982143/python-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8)